# javascript onclick decrement issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make images slide show after completing one all slide show
when I can click on the back button that time it showing undefined

Plz, check this function prevFun.

```js
const slide = document.querySelector("#imgSlide");
const img = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
const img_Length = img.length;
var i = 1;
const nextFun = () => {
  if (i < img_Length) {
    slide.src = `images/${img[i]}.jpg`;
    i++;
    console.log(i);
  }
};
const prevFun = () => {
  if (i < 0) {
    return;
  } else if (i <= img.length) {
    slide.src = `images/${img[i]}.jpg`;
    i--;
    console.log(i);
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <img src="images/a.jpg" alt="img" id="imgSlide" />
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="left" onclick="prevFun()">
      <</div>
        <div class="right" onclick="nextFun()">></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Arshad, hello. 

When are you seeing 'undefined'? I cannot duplicate that while running the code snippet.

Also two suggestions for prevFun: in the 'else if' area you aren't using the img_Length variable you set above.  And i < 0 conflicts with the i <= img.length; when i = 0 the control passes to the else if where i is set to -1 which is not what you want (I think).

Comment: after completion all images slides after that if i can click on the prevFun then it displaying undefined

Comment: same code or conditions are working in react but here is not working

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work. Are these results not what you expect?

```js
const img = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
let i = 1;

function increment() {
  if(i >= img.length) return i;
  return ++i;
}

function decrement() {
  if (i < 1) return i;
  if (i <= img.length) {
    return --i;
  }
}

console.log(increment()); // 2
console.log(increment()); // 3
console.log(decrement()); // 2
console.log(decrement()); // 1
console.log(decrement()); // 0
console.log(decrement()); // 0
console.log(decrement()); // 0
console.log(decrement()); // 0
console.log(increment()); // 1
console.log(increment()); // 2
console.log(increment()); // 3
console.log(increment()); // 4
console.log(increment()); // 4
console.log(increment()); // 4
console.log(increment()); // 4
```

Comment: here also iam facing same problem

Comment: undefined.jpg:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/slide_images/images/undefined.jpg 404 (Not Found)